# How to automatically sign in to my website from chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, iis, windows-authentication, windows-server

I published my website, moved them to Windows Server 2022, IIS 10 and I am using windows authentication.
When I open the site in Google Chrome I get a sign in prompt for user name and password. I want to pass the current windows user credentials and login them automatically. The user shouldn't see anything from this login method.

I tried to change settings in internet options, as I know chrome uses those settings. I also checked group policy settings. Maybe I should run a script for this somewhere?

Comment: could you try adding the site url in the trusted site list

Comment: I already tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you tried to add you website in the Chrome policies AuthServerAllowlist and/or AuthNegotiateDelegateAllowlist ?

Comment: Yes, but nothing changed

Comment: could you try adding this code in the web.config file: <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>